# Javascript and Canvas - Animating a Sine wave

Tags: javascript, canvas, trigonometry

So, I have the following code to animate something upwards... it's very basic...

```
SetInterval(function() {
   particlesY -= 1;
}, 10);
```

Then a loop as such:

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
ctx.drawRect(50, particlesY, 32, 32);
```

This works fine, but I want a bit of X-Axis variation - I can use `Math.random()` to get a random direction, but the result is very jerky and pretty much laughable.

I figured that a sine wave would give me a nice smooth X-Axis change.

Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sine wave should be fairly straightforward:

```
ctx.drawRect( Math.sin(particlesY) * 100, particlesY, 32, 32);
```

Comment: `Math.sin()` takes radians - decrementing `particlesY` by 1 each loop will only give you 6.28 samples per cycle...

Comment: sorry yes, I was thinking that after I answered, it would be wise to divide particlesY by some scalar before obtaining the sin.